# How can I compute recursive QR-factorization?

Tags: matrix-decomposition, recursive-algorithms, system-identification

I wonder if it's possible to find the $Q$ and $R$ matrices from this QR-equation with only compute QR at one time only:

$$A = QR$$

if, the first column of $A$ got removed and then a new column got added to $A$.

I take it again: Assume that we first got our data matrix $A$ and we compute $Q$ and $R$. Then we change our data matrix $A$ by remove first column and add new data column to $A$. That means $Q$ and $R$ are going to change. Can we compute the new $Q$ and $R$ if we know the new data column of $A$ and the past $Q$ and $R$?

If you wonder what I got this question from. I got this from the paper *Recursive Subspace Identification Algorithm using the Propagator Based Method, 2017*.

Comment: Do you mean that the first column gets removed, such that the old second column of $A$ becomes the new first column, the old third column becomes the new second column ect. and that new last column of $A$ becomes the new column, or do you mean that the first column of $A$ gets replaced with the new column?

Comment: Yes! I mean this one "Do you mean that the first column gets removed, such that the old second column of A becomes the new first column, the old third column becomes the new second column ect. and that new last column of A becomes the new column".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do exactly that using Givens rotations. Detailed derivations and explicit algorithms can be found here: http://eprints.ma.man.ac.uk/1192/1/qrupdating_12nov08.pdf.

The gist of it is something like this. Adding a column to the matrix is in some sense trivial:
$$\begin{pmatrix}A & \vec v\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}Q & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} R & \vec v\end{pmatrix} = \tilde Q_0 \tilde R_0\,,$$
with $\tilde Q_0$ nicely orthogonal -- except for the pesky little detail that the new $\tilde R_0$ is not upper triangular. However, note that we can apply a set of rotations to both $\tilde Q_0$ and $\tilde R_0$,
$$\tilde Q = \tilde Q_0 G_1 \dotsm G_k\,,\qquad \tilde R = G_1^T \dotsm G_k^T \tilde R_0\,,$$
that preserve both the product $\tilde Q_0 \tilde R_0 = \tilde Q \tilde R$ and the orthogonality of $\tilde Q$ but can have an effect on the triangularity of $\tilde R$. It's then just a matter of finding the proper sequence of rotations to turn $\tilde R_0$ into an upper-triangular matrix $\tilde R$.

For deleting a column, the logic goes backwards in some sense: if we could write $A = LQ$ as
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}A_0 & \vec v\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}Q_0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}R_0 & \vec v\end{pmatrix}\,,$$
then removing a column would simply amount to ignoring the last column of $R$ and the last row and column of $Q$. We can use a sequence of Givens rotations to do just that.

One interesting observation is that when adding a column, you can update the $R$ factor without keeping track of the $Q$ factor. This isn't true for deleting columns, so if you can make your update not involve deletes you can save a lot of memory.

Comment: So all I need to do is to remove and replace columns only?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. *If* you want to update $R$ and $Q$ so that you effectively add a column to the product $RQ$, you start by padding $Q$ as described and performing the necessary Givens rotations by multiplying rows and columns of $Q$ and $R$ accordingly -- the detailed algorithm is in the link. To update $R$ and $Q$ so that a column is removed, you need to apply a set of rotations first, then drop some rows and/or columns of $Q$ and $R$.